# tensorflow keras datasets doesn't load ConnectionError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my code Everytime I run I get connectionError [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) =  mnist.load_data()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(training_images[0])
print(training_labels[0])
print(training_images[0])

training_images = training_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam',
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

A solution from [Cannot load any datasets from tf.keras, gives error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222200/cannot-load-any-datasets-from-tf-keras-gives-error-winerror-10054-an-existing) didn't work for me.
I replaced those codes like this which didn't work:

```
    # Lint as python3
# Copyright 2018 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================
# pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
"""Utilities for file download and caching."""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from abc import abstractmethod
from contextlib import closing
import errno
import functools
import gc
import hashlib
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.dummy
import os
import random
import shutil
import signal
import sys
import tarfile
import threading
import time
import weakref
import zipfile

import numpy as np
import six
import requests
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
from six.moves.urllib.error import HTTPError
from six.moves.urllib.error import URLError

from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.io_utils import path_to_string
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
from tensorflow.python.util import tf_inspect
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export


try:
  import queue
except ImportError:
  import Queue as queue
```

I am using Windows machine and python 3.8 without any python virtual environment or anaconda.

Comment: You can check the solutions from these posts and try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109688/ https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32314

Comment: It feels like miracle after a longing. Still wondering and looking for a possible explanation why IDLE breaks down for this program.

Comment: It works on PyCharm also.But The vanilla IDLE seems to break down out of no reason.